# Not able to remove multiple whitespace(s) in a string in java

Tags: java, regex

Problem:
Can't remove multiple white spaces in a string while working in eclipse editor

Context:

```
String myString1 ="aye  bye  tye  ";
String myString2 =myString1.replaceAll("\\s+","");
System.out.println("replaced string ="+myString2);
```

In the output the white spaces are not removed and the result is the same as the string,

```
replaced string =aye  bye  tye
```

is getting printed

But if there is only one white space between the words like,

```
String myString1 ="aye bye tye";
```

the result is correctly coming as below:

```
replaced string =ayebyetye
```

I wonder where I am going wrong?

Comment: sorry but for both input strings `aye  bye  tye` and `aye bye tye` I'm getting correct output `replaced string =ayebyetye` so what is the problem again?

Comment: can't reproduce your first stmt http://ideone.com/NdoLEt

Comment: the output of the first example is not the one you get. I get the results that you wish when I run it. Are you sure that you use the correct variables in your actual code (e.g., that you don't mess `myString1` with `myString2`?)

Comment: @LaurentiuL. Am trying your suggestion ...my workstation is pretty far from internet station will keep you posted

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I am not sure of your case I checked the link too...but for me it does not replace it correctly with one whitespace...I tested that again

Comment: @dkr you will need to adapt it of course. Second argument will not be a single space ' ' but an empty one ''. But for all intents and purposes it should answer your question.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: I am reading these values from my jsp throigh tag additon feature and receiving it in my controller to replace the extra white spaces before i can store it as an attribute to my bo..... as told in my previous comments i m working away from internet station so would keep you posted if i am able to solve it or still better read my folly :/

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Does it work also for
String myString ="sachin  kambli    dravid      "; for me it fails ...

Comment: @dkr `String1.replaceAll("\\s+","");` does replace all the whitespaces with empty string. And make sure that you're printing the string which was the result you got after replacement.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. Hi Lauren, I got the solution selected as preferred answer. I am reading the values from a jsp page through javascript for an input field over which a tags plugin has been enabled. As suggested by nhahtdh I I used the regex fro removing all Unicode for spaces and it worked. I guess it is not a duplicate of "REGEX to replace multiple Spaces with a single space "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only guess that the spaces are not really space character (U+0020), but some Unicode space character, like U+00A0 NO BREAK SPACE. `\s` by default only matches space characters in the ASCII range, so they are not removed.

If you want to remove all Unicode spaces, you have to enable the [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag with inline construct `(?U)`

```
String myString2 = myString1.replaceAll("(?U)\\s+", "");
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. But I was just using the spacebar key only. I guess the eclipse editor replaces this with some other Unicode value than U+0020. I tried this in a Tester.java class in eclipse for three strings with different set of values and whitespaces. It worked for only one of the three cases and failed for others where the whitespace was more than one as mentioned in my post (Question).

Comment: @dkr: In such cases, you might want to inspect the file with a hex editor (for example, you can use `xxd` in *nix environment). It should reveal what causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use space in the replacement part so that one or more spaces would be replaced by a single space character.

```
String myString2 = myString1.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

or

```
String myString2 = myString1.replaceAll("(\\s)+", "$1");
```

Comment: I don't really think that's what the OP wants - in his second example he stated `the result is correctly coming as below` and there were no spaces in the output string.

Comment: ya, later I realized. But his first statement is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Why the

```
String myString2 =myString1.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Is not an option? You don't need a regex at all